# Vertical Line with Branches in css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I trying to draw a vertical line with multiple branches left and right sides of the line. I used `pseudo` class div after but when right side text there is a problem in positioning the arrow.Is there any other way to write this class.Can anyone suggest me how to write this class?

Any help appreciated.
[image]
for inspiration look at this [demo](http://businesslounge-demo.rtthemes.com/timelines/)

```css
.at-timeline .timeline--details {
  position: relative;
}
.at-timeline .timeline--single {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.at-timeline .timeline--details,
.at-timeline .time--date {
    flex-basis: 14%;
    padding: 15px 50px;
}
.text-right { text-align: right;}
.at-timeline .timeline--details:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 35px;
  height: 2px;
  top: 17%;
  right: 0;
  background: #2783e8;
}
.at-timeline:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  height: 300%;
  top: 15%;
  left: 24%;
  background: #2783e8;
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline at-timeline" style="padding: 100px;">
 <div class="timeline--single">
  <div class="timeline--details text-right">
   <h4 class="timeline--title">Title</h4>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum non dolor ultricies, porttitor justo non, pretium mi.</p>
  </div>
  <span class="time--date">
   <span class="date">01</span>
   <span class="month">January</span>
   <span class="year">2017</span>
  </span>
 </div>
 <div class="timeline--single">
  <span class="time--date text-right">
   <span class="date">01</span>
   <span class="month">January</span>
   <span class="year">2017</span>
  </span>
  <div class="timeline--details reverse">
   <h4 class="timeline--title">Title</h4>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum non dolor ultricies, porttitor justo non, pretium mi.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="timeline--single">
  <div class="timeline--details text-right">
   <h4 class="timeline--title">Title</h4>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum non dolor ultricies, porttitor justo non, pretium mi.</p>
  </div>
  <span class="time--date">
   <span class="date">01</span>
   <span class="month">January</span>
   <span class="year">2017</span>
  </span>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but do you want to write your own code? or also use the demo?

Comment: I want to use same HTML classes.i don't want to change HTML only in  CSS I want to change the code.

Comment: I simply extracted the code from the demo, and I used their CSS. maybe it helps you https://jsfiddle.net/Micio/27ehjpt3/

Comment: @Leo second line should be on right side.

Comment: widen the output as much as possible, otherwise a media query goes into operation

Comment: we can use :nth-child(). but I don't know how i will do.

Comment: use 'nth-child ()' for what?

Comment: `:before`  line.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not understanding what you're trying to tell me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd simplify the html, tracking right/left on each row and altering the elements order could be a problem and annoying for screen readers or mobile version (In a narrow screen the "two sides" could be far from best obtion, using just right side saves space)
:nth-child(odd) let you change the position, alignment, etc of the elements, alternatively on each "row".

```css
div{box-sizing:border-box;}
.timeline-item{
  color:blue;
}
.timeline{overflow:hidden;position:relative;}
.timeline:after{display:block;content:" ";width:2px;height:100%;position:absolute;left:50%;background:green;}/*vertical bar*/
h4{margin:0;}

.timeline-item .timeline-date{clear:both;float:left;width:50%;text-align:right;;padding:0 1rem 1rem;}
.timeline-item .timeline-details{float:right;width:50%;text-align:left;padding:0 1rem 1rem;position:relative;}
.timeline-item:nth-child(odd){
  color:red;
}
.timeline-item:nth-child(odd) .timeline-date{float:right;text-align:left;}
.timeline-item:nth-child(odd) .timeline-details{float:left;text-align:right}

/*branches*/
.timeline-item .timeline-details:before{display:block;content:" ";height:2px;width:1rem;background-color:green;position:absolute;top:0.5em;left:0;}
.timeline-item:nth-child(odd) .timeline-details:before{right:0;left:initial;}
```

```html
<div class="timeline at-timeline">
 <div class="timeline-item">
    <div class="timeline-date">
   <span class="date">01</span>
   <span class="month">January</span>
   <span class="year">2017</span>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline-details">
   <h4>Title</h4>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum non dolor ultricies, porttitor justo non, pretium mi.</p>
  </div>
   </div>
     
      <div class="timeline-item">
    <div class="timeline-date">
   <span class="date">01</span>
   <span class="month">January</span>
   <span class="year">2017</span>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline-details">
   <h4>Title</h4>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum non dolor ultricies, porttitor justo non, pretium mi.</p>
  </div>
   </div>
   <div class="timeline-item">
    <div class="timeline-date">
   <span class="date">01</span>
   <span class="month">January</span>
   <span class="year">2017</span>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline-details">
   <h4>Title</h4>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum non dolor ultricies, porttitor justo non, pretium mi.</p>
  </div>
   </div>
   <div class="timeline-item">
    <div class="timeline-date">
   <span class="date">01</span>
   <span class="month">January</span>
   <span class="year">2017</span>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline-details">
   <h4>Title</h4>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum non dolor ultricies, porttitor justo non, pretium mi.</p>
  </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could accomplish it using absolute positioning and a bunch of margins and paddings like in this snippet

```css
.at-timeline {
  position: relative;
  width: 70%;
}

.at-timeline:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  height: 900px;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  background: #2783e8;
}
.timeline--single {
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px 0;
}
.timeline--single:nth-child(odd) .timeline--details {
  margin-right: 50%;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 50px;
}

.timeline--single:nth-child(odd) .time--date{
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.timeline--single:nth-child(even) .time--date{ 
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  top: 0px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.timeline--single:nth-child(even) .timeline--details {
  margin-left: 50%;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

.at-timeline .timeline--details:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 35px;
  height: 2px;
  top: 10px;
  background: #2783e8;
}

.timeline--single:nth-child(odd) .timeline--details:before { 
  right: 50%;
}
.timeline--single:nth-child(even) .timeline--details:before { 
  left: 50%;
}

.timeline--title {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline at-timeline" style="padding: 100px;">
 <div class="timeline--single">
  <div class="timeline--details text-right">
   <h4 class="timeline--title">Title</h4>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum non dolor ultricies, porttitor justo non, pretium mi.</p>
  </div>
  <span class="time--date">
   <span class="date">01</span>
   <span class="month">January</span>
   <span class="year">2017</span>
  </span>
 </div>
 <div class="timeline--single">
  <span class="time--date text-right">
   <span class="date">01</span>
   <span class="month">January</span>
   <span class="year">2017</span>
  </span>
  <div class="timeline--details reverse">
   <h4 class="timeline--title">Title</h4>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum non dolor ultricies, porttitor justo non, pretium mi.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="timeline--single">
  <div class="timeline--details text-right">
   <h4 class="timeline--title">Title</h4>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum non dolor ultricies, porttitor justo non, pretium mi.</p>
  </div>
  <span class="time--date">
   <span class="date">01</span>
   <span class="month">January</span>
   <span class="year">2017</span>
  </span>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: a few microseconds are negligible

Comment: I'll have to find the article, but a simple layout like this (absolutes) vs Flexbox is actually more like half a second.  The issues arises that absolute within absolutes cause all rendering engines to n+1 pass over the dom to correctly render.  Depends on the number of elements as well.  Sure your example could only be 400ms slower, but where else are absolutes used on the same page.  It can add up pretty quickly.  Best to avoid it, especially when there are flat out better technologies.

Answer (score 2):

I have kept all your HTML without changes, I just removed the inline style and changed it for margin to make the layout easier.

On the other hand, I have tried not to use absolute units, except when trying to adapt to other units already set.

The h4 margin is the same as Chrome default stylesheet. I just made it explicit to make it more portable across other browsers

```css
.at-timeline .timeline--details {
  position: relative;
}
.at-timeline .timeline--single {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.at-timeline .timeline--details,
.at-timeline .time--date {
    flex-basis: 50%;
    padding: 15px 50px;
    position: relative;
}
.at-timeline h4 {
  margin-top: 1.33em;
}
.text-right { 
    text-align: right;
}
.at-timeline .timeline--details:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 35px;
  height: 2px;
  top: calc(15px + 1.83em);   /* padding details +`margin top h4 + 0.5em */
  right: 0;
  background: #2783e8;
}
.at-timeline .reverse:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 35px;
  height: 2px;
  top: calc(15px + 1.83em);
  left: 0;
  background: #2783e8;
}

.at-timeline {
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px 100px;
}
.at-timeline:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  background: #2783e8;
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline at-timeline">
 <div class="timeline--single">
  <div class="timeline--details text-right">
   <h4 class="timeline--title">Title</h4>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum non dolor ultricies, porttitor justo non, pretium mi.</p>
  </div>
  <span class="time--date">
   <span class="date">01</span>
   <span class="month">January</span>
   <span class="year">2017</span>
  </span>
 </div>
 <div class="timeline--single">
  <span class="time--date text-right">
   <span class="date">01</span>
   <span class="month">January</span>
   <span class="year">2017</span>
  </span>
  <div class="timeline--details reverse">
   <h4 class="timeline--title">Title</h4>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum non dolor ultricies, porttitor justo non, pretium mi.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="timeline--single">
  <div class="timeline--details text-right">
   <h4 class="timeline--title">Title</h4>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum non dolor ultricies, porttitor justo non, pretium mi.</p>
  </div>
  <span class="time--date">
   <span class="date">01</span>
   <span class="month">January</span>
   <span class="year">2017</span>
  </span>
 </div>
</div>
```